# hide div that contains <p> that contains "text" - how to

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="example">
 <ul>
  <p>text</p>
 </ul>
<div>
```

i need to hide div itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Original Answer:

<strike>$("div p:contains('text'))").hide();</strike>

This won't work because it hides the `<p>` and not the `<div>`. We also need to employ `:has`.

```
$("div:has(p:contains('text'))").hide();
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/fs4yf/)**

Comment: @daniel - I just realised that after posting. Looking at an elegant solution now...

Comment: Then try `$("div p:contains('text')").parent('div').hide();` instead. Russ, is this a sensible way to do this?

Comment: except that in my case,somehow,wants me to specify id of the element, otherwise not working??? weird

Answer (score 1):

The solutions with `parent()` can't guarantee that the right parent is being used.

Use this:

```
$('div').has("p:contains('text')").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div p:contains('text')").closest("div").hide();
```

Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7qmwj/8/

Comment: @Peeter: the `p` may not be (and, in the given example, _is not_) a _direct_ descendent of the `div`. Your `parent()` call is broken.

Comment: This is why this doesn't work - http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/7qmwj/7/ Only the `<div>` with id example should be hidden.

Comment: Broken again - http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/7qmwj/9/ :( (at least according to the OP's question, although it may not be specific enough to know if this is right or wrong). Actually, using `parents('div')` yields the same outcome as my answer, so +1 for the persistence :)

Comment: @Peter: That's still not right. You don't know that it's the "closest" `div`.